# image_image plugin does not exist

Tags: 8, media

Trying to build a content module (= a module that adds a content type) for drupal 8 but I get the following error on install, the error isnt very informative and Im stuck. The module has a image upload field, and I assume its whats throwing the error but the code for it is copied out of drupals export

> Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "image_image" plugin does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 52 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php).

Code is at the following
https://github.com/ShadyRabbit/drupalIssue

Update: I found the answer myself: ***`entity_view_display` was the same as `entity_form_display` resulting in the error of the content type***

Comment: What is "content module"?

Comment: A module that adds a content type.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere you specified image_image, a widget, formatter or field type. There is no such thing, find it and correct it.

You get better help if you share your code.

Comment: Added https://github.com/ShadyRabbit/drupalIssue